# Does using incognito mode protect from browser fingerprinting techniques?

Tags: privacy, cookies, anonymity, chrome, firefox

As far as I understand Chrome's and Firefox's incognito modes mean nothing is persisted. Cookies, Offline Storage, IndexedDB, cache, everything is flushed when you exit.

Does this still leave a way (not based on IP-address nor behaviour analysis) for sites you visit to trace and de-anonymise you?

Comment: @drewbenn Panopticlick is largely useless for actual fingerprinting tests. It only exists to raise awareness. It is extremely limited in what fingerprinting vectors it uses.

Answer (score 4):

In general, incognito mode isn't effective against fingerprinting. Fingerprinting looks at characteristics of your browser/system like your user agent, plugin lists, and screen resolution, none of which can be stopped by refusing to save (or clearing) data from your visit to the site (which is all incognito mode does).

Comment: Is the plugin list still available in modern browsers?

Comment: @curiousguy Yes. I just ran [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) and it still captures it as of Chrome 77.

Comment: Indeed. This is *unsettling*.

Answer (score 1):

With [Fingerprintjs2](http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs2/), Chrome had the same fingerprint in incognito as without. Firefox had a different fingerprint with private browsing than without, but that fingerprint did persist after closing and reopening private browsing.